# Node Explorer throws Serialization exception when any transactions are performed by the Corda Node

Tags: corda

**Scenario:**

1. I am running the irs-demo application on Linux instance
2. NodeExplorer is installed on Windows instance
3. I try to connect to BankA node of irs-demo, to view the nodes vault and transactions with the help of NodeExplorer, using
   following command:

   `java -jar corda-tools-explorer-3.2-corda.jar`
4. Following are the credentials of PartyA that I have used to login to NodeExplorer

   ```
     Corda Node: <IP_address_of_Linux_instance>
     Port: <RPC_port_number>
     Username: <RPC_user>
     Password: <RPC_password>
   ```

**Observations:**

1. When no transactions are performed by PartyA, I can successfully login to the NodeExplorer and connect to PartyA, using about credentials
2. When I make few transactions for PartyA using Web Browser, and then try to login to the NodeExplorer using same credentials, following exception is thrown:

   ```
   [INFO ] 05:02:07,923 [JavaFX Application Thread] (InternalUtils.kt:208) internal.RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 1084 msec {}  
   00:02  WARN: [kryo] Unable to load class net.corda.irs.contract.InterestRateSwap$State with kryo's ClassLoader. Retrying with current..
   [ERROR] 05:02:09,791 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] (ClientConsumerImpl.java:1122) core.client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage {}
   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: net.corda.irs.contract.InterestRateSwap$State
   Serialization trace:
   data (net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState)
   state (net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef)
   states (net.corda.core.node.services.Vault$Page)
   snapshot (net.corda.core.messaging.DataFeed)
   value (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success)
   at     com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:160) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:160) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:693) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:782) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:132) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:97) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:80) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1.execute(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:95) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.deserialize(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:94) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:360) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:256) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.access$artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:69) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$2.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:197) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$2.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:69) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandlerKt$sam$MessageHandler$6fb61eb3.onMessage(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.irs.contract.InterestRateSwap$State
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
   at     com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
   ... 48 more
   ```

**Note:**
I got the same exception, if I run the irs-demo application and NodeExplorer on single windows instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key exception is:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.irs.contract.InterestRateSwap$State`

This indicates that the Node Explorer does not have the IRS CorDapp installed, and cannot therefore deserialise `InterestRateSwap$State` objects.

This appears to be a bug. I've raised it here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1992.

Comment: Thank you for considering it as a bug. We have installed IRS CorDapp at the Corda node, for which we want to connect the node explorer. However it seems to be an issue due to the recent updates related to serialization library changed from Kryo to AMQP (just guessing.. :P)

Answer (score 0):

This is the temporary way that you need put the miss class file into Node Explore by manual, after that you will find the transaction flow into explorer.